# Sails.js: Controller never called when submitting form

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Sails.js. I'm stuck with a problem : I cannot manage to call a controller when submitting a form.

Here is my form in my ejs file :

```
  <form method="post" action="/calibers/add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fname">Name of the new caliber:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="7,62x54 R">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn">
  </form>
```

Here is how the mapping is done in routes.js :

```
  'GET /calibers/view':      { action: 'calibers/view'},
  'POST /calibers/add':      { action: 'calibers/add'},
```

here is the called controller: add.js:

```js
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'Add calibers',

  description: 'Adding new caliber to calibers list',

  inputs: {
          name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
          },
  },

  exits: {
    success: {
        responseType: 'view',
        viewTemplatePath: 'pages/welcome'
      },
  },

  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    console.log("Called function");

    let newCal = await Caliber.create({name: inputs.name});

    // All done.
    if (!newCal) {
       return exits.invalid({
         message: 'New caliber could\'t be added'
       });
     }

     return exits.success({
       message: 'New caliber successfully added',
       data: userRecord
     });}

};
```

When I click on the submit button of my form, the controller never seems to be called, and I'm redirected to a simple "Forbidden". What is going on ? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're using the action2 format you should have:

The action Add in api/controllers/caliber/add

The routing:

```
'POST /api/v1/caliber/add': { action: 'caliber/add' }'
```

In the view file:

```
<form method="post" action="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Although I'd advise you use longer action names as you might have add in several controllers which might lead to issues.

It is all in the docs, please read them.